# Accessing Mainframe transactions using .Net 4

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking at re-writing an application (currently in C) which uses HIS 2004 (Could use 2009 if required) to access mainframe transactions.

Is there a decent framework which I could use to connect and call mainframe transactions and relay any infromation into the existing system? ( I am developing in a .Net 4 environment) to remove the c coded requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't known HIS very well but I remember that it can expose Mainframe (CICs ?) transactions as COM components so it should be just a matter of using these components from within your .Net app.

Best

Comment: +1, that's accurate afaik.  COM is directly usable from .NET.  Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253023%28BTS.10%29.aspx